# Why is there no XPath syntax for namespace-qualified nodes?

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces, xml-namespaces

Some of the nodes in an XML document have namespaces, specified with a defined prefix.

It is possible to specify *local-name()* in XPath 1.0 and so ignore namespaces.

However, I want to enable the writer of the XPath to find nodes using their full namespace-qualified name as an identifier.

The recommended way is to add namespace declarations in the invoking code (in my case, Java). But this means that the person writing Xpath does not have the ability to work with namespaces!

How do we find nodes by their fully qualified names using pure XPath?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you are asking why there is a need to declare a namespace using an instruction like `addNamespace("abc","http://example.com")` which then allows to do an Xpath query like `/abc:node`, instead of somehow using `http://example.com` directly in the query. Have I interpreted the question correctly?

Comment: @Jong Bor Yes, that's it. It would be good  to use the prefix abc directly in the XPath query after declaring that abc=http://example.com somehow within the XPath. I understand that XPath expressions are short and it would not be usual to insert definitions in it, but there is nothing technically preventing that from being possible in XPath.

Comment: BTW good question, +1. Since prefixes are supposed to be merely insignificant syntactic sugar, whereas the namespace URIs are what's significant, you would think that it might be useful to match on a node name are namespace URI without having to mess with a prefix -- especially if  XPath itself provides no way to declare a prefix.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not sure what you meant by "as an identifier".

> How do we find nodes by their fully qualified names using pure XPath?

In XPath 1.0, by using local-name() and [namespace-uri()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Node-Set-Functions), e.g.

```
"*[local-name() = 'foo' and namespace-uri() = 'http://my.org/ns/2.0']"
```

In XPath 2.0, there is a richer set of functions related to namespaces, e.g. [`namespace-uri-from-QName()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-namespace-uri-from-QName). But I'm not sure they improve on the above for what you want.

Comment: Good, that makes sense. A bit clumsy -- I'd rather write something like http://my.org/ns/2.0|foo without these function names, and even better to somehow use prefixes, declaring them in XPath rather than in Java -- but this does meet the requirement.

Comment: By "using their full namespace-qualified name as an identifier" I just meant that you should be able to reference nodes precisely, with namespace+local-name. Your answer shows how.

Comment: @JoshuaFox: I agree, it would be very handy to be able to declare prefixes in XPath itself. I imagine there are some reasons why "they" decided not to include that in XPath, but it does seem like a big gap, since the workaround is so verbose.

Comment: @LarsH is this kind of expression applicable to selection of attributes?

Comment: @ArtemOboturov: yes. Just change `*` to `@*`. (Note that attributes do not inherit the default namespace of their ancestors.)

Answer (score 6):

XPath 3.0, which is currently in working draft status, will include a literal expression for [URI qualified QNames](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#doc-xpath30-EQName) allowing users to directly specify the namespace uri.

> Here are some examples of EQNames:
>
> - pi is a lexical QName without a namespace prefix.
> - math:pi is a lexical QName with a namespace prefix.
> - "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math":pi specifies the namespace URI using a URILiteral; it is not a lexical QName.

I think [Saxon 9.3](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) includes a preview implementation of xpath 3.0, which should be usable through the Java api.

Comment: Correct, though 3.0 features can at present only be enabled in the commercial editions of the product. Questions like "why was this feature not in earlier versions" are always hard to answer - either no-one proposed it or they didn't push hard enough, or they had to compete with rival proposals for solving the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use namespaces during your XPath queries. In Java, what you need to provide is an implementation of [NamespaceContext](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html) if you also want to use prefixes in those queries instead of the fully qualified namespace all the time. Just add an instance of `NamespaceContext` to your `XPath` - I'll assume you use the standard JDK implementation - but the concept is applicable to Jaxen or others as well.

Then you can perform queries such as `//customns:Element`.

If you don't or can't use a `NamespaceContext` (for whatever reason) then the only solution seems to be using the `local-name` and `namespace-uri` functions:

```
Document doc = ...;
XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String name = "Element";
String ns = "http://www.custom.org/#";
String expr = "//*[local-name() = '"+name+" and namespace-uri() = '"+ns+"']";
Node node = ((NodeList)xp.evaluate(expr, doc, XPathConstants.NODESET)).item(0);
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I am willing to use full  namespaces names and not prefixes? In other words, something like. Can I avoid declaring the namespaces in the Java? My goal  is to read in XPath expressions from an external source, and so I'd rather not have to specify this separately.

Comment: That depends on how the source looks like - if you just have an expression //abc:Element and no namespace declaration then in theory you are stuck - no way to know what abc points to. But if you can be absolutely sure that those external expressions have the same prefixes than your working document, then you could still look up the corresponding namespaces in your document and then either build a NamespaceContext or not use it at all. I'll update my answer outlining how to do so.

Comment: Unfortunately, there seems to be [no other solution](http://www.jguru.com/forums/view.jsp?EID=1073634) than a combination of local-name() and namespace-uri().

Answer (score 0):

The spec for XPath 3.0 says:

```
Q{http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math}pi
```

This works at this moment (October 2015) for example in eXist-db.

Comment: @e4c5: XML likes to use URIs for things in its literal syntax. You should have read the answer more carefully.

Comment: @NathanTuggy yes you are right, while moderating that did appear as a link only answer (the comment is auto inserted by the system) I have now deleted that comment.