# Add namespace in xpath in XmlFile Element (Wix Util Extension)

Tags: wix, wix-extension

The `ElementPath` attribute of  `XmlFile` element in wix accepts an xpath to select the target. How can I include namespace prefixes in this xpath?

Comment: Adding the namespace before the tag doesn't work? E.g. `/myns:MyTagName`

Comment: The target xml document uses a default namespace at the root element without any namespace prefix and I could not find any way to associate prefixes with xml namespaces in XmlFile element.

Comment: I didn't try it myself, but what I've found you have to declare this default namespace also in your XSLT-file (where you have access to, I suppose) using a prefix, e.g. `a:xmlns='http://my.default.namespace/taken/from/xml/file'` and then use this prefix in your XSLT-file to access the element, e.g. `/a:MyTagName`.

Comment: Sorry, confused the transformation of a heat-result with XSLT. Ignore my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue entry](https://wixtoolset.org/issues/3000/) it seems to be a bug or better: a not implemented feature, as an eventually existing default namespace is not exposed by the `util:XmlFile`-element.
According to the first comment in this entry you can work around this issue by using `util:XmlConfig` which should look in the empty namespace for the needed nodes / elements.

**Edit:** I've found another method for using it: according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7056753/1785391) by @LarsH you can use something like the following (didn't test it myself, but as it seem to be a valid XPath 1.0 expression, it should normally work):

```
"*[local-name() = 'foo' and namespace-uri() = 'http://my.org/ns/2.0']"
```

Remember to *escape* the square brackets, i.e. `[...]` should become `[\[]...[\]]`.